# Merge Before Build Jenkins git plugin option not triggering

Tags: git, jenkins, merge

Our development cycle maintains multiple concurrent release branches.

We want to have a reliable way to expose merge conflicts in release branches as early as possible in the cycle.

In our build jobs in Jenkins, we specify a glob of release* as the branch to build, and specify the git plugin option to "Merge Before Build" to master before the build is commenced.

My expectation here is that the plugin would merge *all* release branches it finds into master before commencing the build of each release branch.

I've set up a dummy repo to test this. The repo has one text file. There are 3 branches:

master (main)
release1 (taken from master)
release2 (taken from master)

I update the same line in the file in release1 and release2 to deliberately create a merge conflict which I have confirmed exists.

Now, when I build the job, I would expect Jenkins to try and merge release1 and release2 into master, where it would encounter the merge conflict and fail, which is what we want.

However, Jenkins doesn't seem to attempt this, despite the "Merge Before Build" option being set.

```
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxxx/test_repo.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxxx/test_repo.git 
 +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 Seen branch in repository origin/master
 Seen branch in repository origin/release1
 Seen branch in repository origin/release2
 Seen 3 remote branches
 Checking out Revision 5b75c954f334a2fc6c683cd7304d4d84826f02cd 
(origin/release2, origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 5b75c954f334a2fc6c683cd7304d4d84826f02cd
 > git rev-list 5b75c954f334a2fc6c683cd7304d4d84826f02cd # timeout=10
 > git rev-list 5b75c954f334a2fc6c683cd7304d4d84826f02cd # timeout=10
 Set build name.
 New build name is '#8 '
[build-sharknado-app] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1678313403112351764.sh
+ cat file.txt
x=7
```

The jobs succeeds and we don't see the merge conflict.

Why is the merge of multiple release* branches to master not happening?

Comment: `git checkout -f 5b75c954f334a2fc6c683cd7304d4d84826f02cd`. A specific commit is checked out so it's in detached HEAD state. The branch `master` is not checked out and thus does not exist locally, although `origin/master` points to `5b75c954f334a2fc6c683cd7304d4d84826f02cd`. This may be the cause.

Comment: That appears to be the issue, but I don't know why a commit is being checked out. I am specifying "origin/release*" as the "Branches to Build" option, and these branch exist. However, only release2 is being merged to master as part of the build.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the Git plugin is acting as designed.

All of the branches are being scanned for revision changes (based on local copy of the git repo in the Jenkins workspace). When none are found, Jenkins only acts on the most recent commit.

The Git plugin is not designed to merge multiple branches to master in the same build.

Where changes are detected on multiple branches, Jenkins launches a new build job for each branch. In each job, the relevant branch is merged to master, but Jenkins checks out master with the -f option, which resets the HEAD on master, so a build conflict that arises from multiple branches being merged to master is not detected.

This means that Jenkins can only detect a merge conflict that arises from merging one branch to another, and not a conflict that arises from merging 2 different branches to the same destination branch.